# Functions as elements of a vector in racket

Tags: racket

How do you represent elements of a vector which are functions/procedures in racket?

I would think it would be something like:

```
#(+ -)
```

But when I retrieve the elements I get the symbols '+ and '-.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that `#(` is a special syntax for reading array literals, not an operator that evaluates the content between parentheses. From the [manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-vector%29):

> When the reader encounters a `#(`, `#[`, or `#{`, it starts parsing a [vector](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28tech._vector%29); see [Vectors](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) for information on vectors.
>   ...
>   In [read-syntax mode](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-syntax%29%29), each recursive read for vector elements is also in [read-syntax](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-syntax%29%29) mode, so that the wrapped vector’s elements are also wrapped as syntax objects, and the vector is immutable.
>
> Examples: `#(1 apple 3)` reads equal to `(vector 1 'apple 3)`

So, you should use the explicit [`vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html) operator:

```
(define a (vector + -))

((vector-ref a 0) 2 3)  ; => 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm getting the impression that racket is a very dense and complicated language when one ventures beyond its most basic features.

Comment: You are welcome (and please mark the answer as accepted if you think that it solves the question). I hope that your impression about the language will be mitigated once you use it a little more. In my opinion, Racket/Scheme is not more complicated than many other commonly used languages (and sometime less complicated!).

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted and I will stick with Racket/Scheme because it is very different from my previous language(s) and therefore an interesting departure.